# Autostart script on vps reboot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, vps, restart, reboot

I have a vps linux ubuntu 16.04 with some server installed.

I'm tired of manually restarting my server all the time.
What can I do solve this problem?

My servers run with a "screen"

All time when i need to restart a server i need do this:

1. (Open the screen) < Screen -r "ScreenName" >
2. (Go inside the folder) < cd /home/server/ >
3. (Start the server) < ./server.sh >
4. (Close the screen) < ctrl a+d >

There is a way to perform all these steps automatically when restarting the server?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is I have a file called `onboot.sh` in my home directory. Contents of that file would be:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/server
screen -Ldm -S ScreenSessionName bash server.sh
```

The `L` is optional. It will create a file called `screenlog.0` in the directory containing the log of the script's output. `-S` Sets the sessionnname. `-d` detaches the screen once it's been created and `-m` enforces to create a new screen session.

For the script to be run on boot I use `cron`. In my case I use `sudo crontab -e` to edit the root user's crontab and append the following line:

```
@reboot sudo -u username bash /home/username/onboot.sh
```

That will run the `onboot.sh` as the given user. If you want it to be run as root you can simply put

```
@reboot bash /home/username/onboot.sh
```

Inside the crontab.

---

## Quicker approach if you need *just* that one script:

Execute `crontab -e` as the user you want the `server.sh` script to be run as.

Append the following line:

```
@reboot cd /home/server && screen -Ldm -S ScreenSessionName bash server.sh
```

Save the file. That's it.